# Can someone help me with Nodal Analysis?

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

[image]

I am not sure if \$ \frac{V_1}{R_2} - \frac{V_2}{R_2} = 0 \$ is correct for node V1. Can someone help me with this question?

Comment: Best to do: sum all currents away from a node = 0. That way the voltage at that particular node will be first in each term. Thus: \$\frac{V_1}{R_1}+\frac{V_1-V_2}{R_2}=0\$ etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Instead it should've been (-V1/R1) - (V1-V2) /R2 = 0 at node with voltage V1.

It is,  as per my thinking,  always good practice to first assign each branch current some direction,  this reduces chances of mistake while applying KCL. If you get -ve answer at the end,  it simply means actual (positive)  branch current is in direction opposite to that assumed.

Assume current through R2 is from V1 to V2.  Applying KCL,

Sum of incoming currents = Sum of outgoing currents  (Instead of using some sign convention for different directions of currents,  equating them makes things easier)

Now comes the main part,
 Current = Potential difference / Impedance (=Resistance)  in this case.

Potential difference across R1 = 0-V1 because we've assumed that current through R1 flows towards the node and for this to happen its ower terminal should be more +ve than its upper terminal. Thus current through R1 = - V1/R1

Similarly for current flowing from node V1 to node V2 through R2 = potential difference / R2 = (V1-V2)  /R2.

Applying KCL yields,  - V1/R1 = (V1-V2) /R2

PS : After finding node voltages if you'd find current through R1 by our assumed equation i. e.  - V1/R1,  you'll see that it would be - ve.  This simply shows that current through R1 is flowing away from the node,  which is quite obvious from the circuit.

Comment: Isn't it that current through R1 is flowing towards the node? @Deep

Comment: That is assumed direction of current, say direction of I1. If you'll find I1 (Considering direction given in fig) it'll come out to be -ve(-1/3A). If you're told to find I1, you are supposed to write -1/3A. However, what this result physically signifies is, current through R1 is +1/3A in direction away from node. -ve sign in this analysis merely shows you that assumed direction of current (towards the node)  is opposite to flow of positive current. What I'm trying to say is V1 is more positive than ground. (V1 = +1/3 V while Ground is 0V,  current flows from higher potential to lower)

Answer (score 1):

When using the nodal analysis you have to sum all the currents that reach that node.

In this case two currents reach node \$V_1\$: \$I_1\$ and \$I_2\$ (In fact these are the same current)

The node equation could be written in the following way:

$$\frac{V_1}{R_1} + \frac{V_1}{R_2} - \frac{V_2}{R_2} = 0 $$

$$ \frac{V_1}{R_2} - \frac{V_2}{R_2} = - \frac{V_1}{R_1} $$